# defining structs in functions with a char array has different sizes

Tags: c

consider this small example

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


void foo(const int size) {

  struct bar {
    char some_arr[size];
  };

  size_t bar_size = sizeof(struct bar);  
  printf("size:  %ld\n", bar_size);
}


int main() {
  foo(5);
  foo(10);
  return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
size:  5
size:  10
```

My naive guess is that we can treat the struct bar as a type generated at runtime. I would like to know why in this case the size of the `struct bar` is different and how this internally works.

Comment: `some_arr` is a VLA, which is an exception for which `sizof` is calculated in the runtime rather than in compile time.

Comment: But i cannot consider some_arr[10] as a VLA right? Hence the difference

Comment: @Barmar But flexible array member is an incomplete type, no? Then `sizeof` can't be applied. Looks like some extension to me.

Comment: @MatErW3len It's not a VLA if the length is a constant.

Comment: AFAIK it is not allowed by the standard to have a variable size array inside a struct. Is it important for your question that `some_arr` is inside a struct?

Comment: The C standard requires a diagnostic for this. However, ICC and GCC allow it when using a language variant not conforming to the standard. If you want to ask questions about what your compiler is doing, rather than what the C standard says, then edit this question or post a new one and say that explicitly, and identify the compiler, its version, and the switches you are compiling with.